# How can I use the shortcut ctrl + # to comment multiple lines of code in Python or C++ using Vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, comments

When I use Jupyter Notebook inside the browser or inside Google Colab I can comment multiple lines of code by selecting them and pressing crtl + #. This also sometimes worked in Visual Code and not only for Python but also for C++ (of course then each line began with a //). However, I have no idea what enabled this behavior and how to reproduce it, it was very convenient. If you have any idea how to enable this, I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **VS Code** you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for comment multiple lines and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for block comment .

Comment: Oh nice Ctrl+(shift)+/ works perfectly, thank you for that! I am still wondering why ctrl+# worked before, but doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

By default, using `Ctrl+/` for commenting a single line and `Shift+Alt+A` for commenting line blocks.

If you want to override this and make a shortcut on your own, press `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the Command Palette and search `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`. After that, VSCode opens a JSON file where you can put your own shortcut.

```json
{
    "key": "Ctrl+Shift+3", // Shift+3 for selecting #
    "command": "editor.action.blockComment" // or editor.action.commentLine
}
```

Add this code snippet inside the square brackets and save the file.